# js/array | Array.push an object with filter into a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to push into an array some unique objects filtered on a key:value pair. Assuming, I have an array of 2 groups id :

```
let groups = [100,200];
```

I'm trying to get a list of users (id and name) of these groups. And filter to only push objects with unique id value in the output array of object named membersRoles.

```
let membersList = [];
groups.forEach(group => {
    x.groupParts.get(group).members.forEach(user => membersList.push({
       id: user.id,
       name: user.username
    }));
});
```

I know that I need to use :

```
filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
```

But I dont know where I can add this. Any help appreciate :)

Comment: Whenever a `for` loop with a `push` in it is written, a kitten cries. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: You can use map function instead of using foreach loop and mostly you can use `filter` method anywhere after your loop is over.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some test data for x and x.groupParts. Right now it's quite hard to determine what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I replace forEach with map() @HereticMonkey and learned that map is faster than forEach with [this article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do that `filter()` after your `forEach()` loop is done. But it would have to use `.find()` rather than `indexOf()`, because you're just testing a specific property, not object equality.

But it's simpler to just test whether the id value is already in the result list before pushing.

```js
let membersList = [];
groups.forEach(group => {
  x.groupParts.get(group).members.forEach(user => {
    if (!membersList.find(({id}) => id == user.id)) {
      membersList.push({
        id: user.id,
        name: user.username
      });
    }
  });
});
```